# Using AirPort Extreme base station as a wireless G to wireless N bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge, airport-extreme

Due to an unfortunate placement of various wall outlets in my new apartment, my ADSL 2 modem + router is not able to be placed next to my [AirPort Extreme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort) base station (AEBS). I'd prefer not to run [Cat 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) cable between them, but I still want to use the wireless N on the AEBS, because it will have a high speed NAS plugged in via gigabit Ethernet, so I want to maximise the wireless transfer speed to my 27" iMac.

Is it possible to use one of the radios in the Airport Extreme to bridge the wireless G network with the router, and the wireless N radio to broadcast normally?

The only traffic going over the G network should be Internet (24 Mbit/s ADSL2) so it should never get saturated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the AEBS supports client mode ( the airport express does though ) and even if it did it would only act as a client not as a client and base station.

Your best bet is to beg/borrow/buy another really cheap G wireless device that does support client mode and connect that to one of the AEBS switch ports, this will achieve what you want.

http://guides.macrumors.com/AirPort